# Is there a GUI based app to manage Google App Engine services?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google Cloud. So far I have just got some experience in using WHM/Cpanel. Is there a similar app that I can install on App Engine to fully control it without using any commands?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to do, most of the common App Engine operations can be controlled from the [Google Cloud Console](http://console.cloud.google.com). Here is a screen shot of the console:

[image]

For example, looking at Google's documentation on [Controlling Access with Firewalls](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls), you can see in the "Creating firewall rules" section that Google gives instructions for doing this in the console (as well as via the command line with `gcloud`, or programmatically via APIS).

Comment: My basic use is to host a domain, write some PHP codes behind it, manage databases, redirects, emails etc. Does Google Cloud Console can make these happen for a semi technical person?

Answer (score 0):

Our App - [NoCommandLine](https://nocommandline.com) -  is a GUI for managing Google App Engine. With the App, you click buttons/icons instead of typing commands at the command line to create, run and deploy your Apps. We also offer a functionality to download your App from GAE (more on that [here](https://nocommandline.com/help/#faq_download_source_code_from_gae))

[image]